# PDOException in Connector.php line 47: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied in iis server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, pdo

I am new in hosting laravel application into iis server. Now I am facing one issue.

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 47: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied
```

In DB connection(.env and database.php files) changed localhost to 127.0.0.1. But the issue not fixed. How to fix this issue? Can you please help me.

Comment: Sounds like the user you're connecting with doesn't have permissions on the database you're trying to use.

Comment: Incorrect host user pass ...update .env file and call cache:config command

Comment: all credentials correct only. I checked

Comment: What does your `Connector.php` look like? Include line 47 and relevant surrounding lines.